# How to have collection where collection origin is not world origin?

Tags: transforms, linked-data, collections

I'm trying create a set of modular 3D pieces in one blender file that I can use to build scenes.  My idea was to create a single file with the modular pieces and then create a second blender file that would link to them to create the scene.  Because I need to export my scene as glTF, I need to import the pieces from my first file wrapped in collections (if I just import the object, the glTF exporter ignores any transform I make to the linked object).

[image]

I have carefully set the pivot points of my model pieces so that they can snap together easily.  Unfortunately, if I put an object in a collection and that object is not at the world origin, when I import it the linked model includes the offset from the origin in my source file:

[image]

I can solve this by moving the model to the world origin, but that causes another problem - now all my model pieces are overlapping each other in a cluttered, unworkable mess.  Is there a way for me to link to my model pieces without having to move everything to the world origin?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there is a way to do it.  Once you add your object to a collection, you then move the 3d cursor to the place where you would like the origin to be, go into the Properties/Object Properties/Collections panel and then select Set Offset From Cursor from the drop down menu.

Answer (score -2):

**Manual Approach** (No Python Script)

Lets assume you have Blender File [A].  We will create one additional File[B]

These steps will move objects to the world origin.  Keep this technique in mind.

- Cursor to world origin
- Select objects and Move Selection to Origin.  If items are parented then Blender manages this.

Next part

- Perform you work of Modelling in File[A] as usual.
- Copy File[A] to new Blender File[B]. [A] and [B] have distinct names.
- In File[B] use the move technique from above. File [B] is now the processed file with world origins at [0,0,0]. Save File[B].
- You may need to delete a previous File[B].
- You do not want to visually model with File[B] because many objects
  are near the origin.
- File[B] is the target of the file append or link

If often use local mode with <kbd>numeric keypad /</kbd>

I am not saying I agree with your analysis of the problem. People
often make copies of files for archive purposes.  File [A] could also have a Python script.  The script or driver can set values on the delta transform or the primary transform in a particular  location.

See the first comment below for additional.

Comment: If the modelling is done in File A, why not just link the model into file B?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying I should save every model piece from my file into a separate file.  While I could do that, it is a lot of extra work and adds a lot of extra files to my directory.  There is also the problem that over time the master file and the exported pieces become out of sync.

Comment: No that is not the intention.  Please see edit. All objects in one file.  If you choose to create archives of files that is your Blender Users Choice.

Comment: So the file B would have the same objects as the file A, just with everything moved to the origin?

Comment: Yes.  The difference is B is only a library for file append/link.